# appetize.io and Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

appetize.io requires .app bundle

From appetize.io: Your .app bundle must represent a simulator build of your app. Look in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/

I assume that with Xamarin those files are in different location. Not sure where. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

The are in your project's root folder, under bin, just like any .NET project

```
project/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/project.app
```

Comment: the confusing part was that app bundle does not have extension .app but i see it. I zipped it as appetize.io requires and uploaded. When I execute it "Error installing app" comes up. So I am wondering whether I am uploading correct bundle or even Xamarin built apps are compatible with appetize.io